# Get The Address Of the Deployer Of Contract In Truffle Test

Tags: truffle, truffle-test

How can I get the address in Truffle that calls functions of the contract by default(When we don't use the  `{from: accounts[i]}` statement)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It defaults to `accounts[0]`

Hope it helps.